# sending data to php file through ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to Ajax I am trying to send some data to a php file to execute a sql query

this is my js file:

```
             function init() {
                var me = $(this);

                $('select').click(function() {
                    var name = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
                    $.ajax({
                           url: "manage.php",
                           type: "post",
                           inData: {"name":name},
                           success: function(data) {
                              //var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

                             console.log(data);
                           }
                    });
                 })
               }

               $(document).ready(init);

         If I try to parse I get subsequent error:
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

if I log the data I get:

```
   YUI_config = {
    "debug": false,
    "base": "http:\/\/13.81.59.55\/lms\/lib\/yuilib\/3.17.2\/",
    "comboBase": "http:\/\/13.81.59.55\/lms\/theme\/yui_combo.php?",
    "combine": true,
    "filter": null,
    "insertBefore": "firstthemesheet",
    "groups": {
      "yui2": {
        "base": "http:\/\/13.81.59.55\/lms\/lib\/yuilib\/2in3\/2.9.0\/build\/",
        "comboBase": "http:\/\/13.81.59.55\/lms\/theme\/yui_combo.php?",
        "combine": true,
        "ext": false,
        "root": "2in3\/2.9.0\/build\/",
        "patterns": {
          "yui2-": {
            "group": "yui2",
            "configFn": yui1ConfigFn
          }
        }
      },
      "moodle": {
        "name": "moodle",
        "base": "http:\/\/13.81.59.55\/lms\/theme\/yui_combo.php?m\/1630666242\/",
        "combine": true,
        "comboBase": "http:\/\/13.81.59.55\/lms\/theme\/yui_combo.php?",
        "ext": false,
        "root": "m\/1630666242\/",
        "patterns": {
          "moodle-": {
            "group": "moodle",
            "configFn": yui2ConfigFn
          }
        },
        "filter": null,
        "modules": {
          "moodle-core-actionmenu": {
            "requires": ["base", "event", "node-event-simulate"]
          },
          "moodle-core-blocks": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "io", "dom", "dd", "dd-scroll", "moodle-core-dragdrop", "moodle-core-notification"]
          },
          "moodle-core-chooserdialogue": {
            "requires": ["base", "panel", "moodle-core-notification"]
          },
          "moodle-core-dragdrop": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "io", "dom", "dd", "event-key", "event-focus", "moodle-core-notification"]
          },
          "moodle-core-event": {
            "requires": ["event-custom"]
          },
          "moodle-core-formchangechecker": {
            "requires": ["base", "event-focus", "moodle-core-event"]
          },
          "moodle-core-handlebars": {
            "condition": {
              "trigger": "handlebars",
              "when": "after"
            }
          },
          "moodle-core-languninstallconfirm": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "moodle-core-notification-confirm", "moodle-core-notification-alert"]
          },
          "moodle-core-lockscroll": {
            "requires": ["plugin", "base-build"]
          },
          "moodle-core-maintenancemodetimer": {
            "requires": ["base", "node"]
          },
          "moodle-core-notification": {
            "requires": ["moodle-core-notification-dialogue", "moodle-core-notification-alert", "moodle-core-notification-confirm", "moodle-core-notification-exception", "moodle-core-notification-ajaxexception"]
          },
          "moodle-core-notification-dialogue": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "panel", "escape", "event-key", "dd-plugin", "moodle-core-widget-focusafterclose", "moodle-core-lockscroll"]
          },
          "moodle-core-notification-alert": {
            "requires": ["moodle-core-notification-dialogue"]
          },
          "moodle-core-notification-confirm": {
            "requires": ["moodle-core-notification-dialogue"]
          },
          "moodle-core-notification-exception": {
            "requires": ["moodle-core-notification-dialogue"]
          },
          "moodle-core-notification-ajaxexception": {
            "requires": ["moodle-core-notification-dialogue"]
          },
          "moodle-core-popuphelp": {
            "requires": ["moodle-core-tooltip"]
          },
          "moodle-core-tooltip": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "io-base", "moodle-core-notification-dialogue", "json-parse", "widget-position", "widget-position-align", "event-outside", "cache-base"]
          },
          "moodle-core_availability-form": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "event", "event-delegate", "panel", "moodle-core-notification-dialogue", "json"]
          },
          "moodle-backup-backupselectall": {
            "requires": ["node", "event", "node-event-simulate", "anim"]
          },
          "moodle-backup-confirmcancel": {
            "requires": ["node", "node-event-simulate", "moodle-core-notification-confirm"]
          },
          "moodle-course-categoryexpander": {
            "requires": ["node", "event-key"]
          },
          "moodle-course-dragdrop": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "io", "dom", "dd", "dd-scroll", "moodle-core-dragdrop", "moodle-core-notification", "moodle-course-coursebase", "moodle-course-util"]
          },
          "moodle-course-formatchooser": {
            "requires": ["base", "node", "node-event-simulate"]
          },
```

I see nothing in my index.php file:

```
               $name = $_POST['name'];
               echo $name;
```

Explain where I am wrong

Comment: In the ajax, `inData:` should just be `data:`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your data, `YUI_config = ` is incorrect Syntax for JSON data.